# Why do I get a "Selection does not contain a main type" message in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class data {

    public static int setoriginal() {   //prompt user to input 4 digit number
        int n = 0;
        int l = 0;

        do {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter a 4 digit number: ");
            n = input.nextInt();

            if (n >= 1000 && n <= 9999) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.err.
                    printf("You did not enter 4 digits\n");
            }

            l = l + 1;
        }
        while (l < 3);

        return n;
    }           //end method

    public static int encrypt(int n) {  //encrypt number inputted by user

        int e1 = (((n / 1000) + 7) / 10);
        int e2 = ((((n % 1000) / 100) + 7) / 10);
        int e3 = ((((n % 100) / 10) + 7) / 10);
        int e4 = ((((n % 10) / 1) + 7) / 10);

        int e = e1 * 1000 + e2 * 100 + e3 * 10 + e4;

        int firstPart = e % 100;
        int lastPart = e / 100;

        int result = firstPart * 100 + lastPart;

        return result;
    }           //end method

    public static int decrypt(int result) { //decrypt encrypted number

        int d1 = (((result / 1000) - 7) * 10);
        int d2 = ((((result % 1000) / 100) - 7) * 10);
        int d3 = ((((result % 100) / 10) - 7) * 10);
        int d4 = ((((result % 10) / 1) - 7) * 10);

        int d = d1 * 1000 + d2 * 100 + d3 * 10 + d4;

        int firstPart1 = d % 100;
        int lastPart1 = d / 100;

        int result1 = firstPart1 * 100 + lastPart1;

        return result1;
    }           //end method

    public static int decrypt1(int n) { //decrypted number inputted by user

        int dd1 = (((n / 1000) - 7) * 10);
        int dd2 = ((((n % 1000) / 100) - 7) * 10);
        int dd3 = ((((n % 100) / 10) - 7) * 10);
        int dd4 = ((((n % 10) / 1) - 7) * 10);

        int dd = dd1 * 1000 + dd2 * 100 + dd3 * 10 + dd4;

        int firstPart1 = dd % 100;
        int lastPart1 = dd / 100;

        int result1 = firstPart1 * 100 + lastPart1;

        return result1;
    }           //end method

    public static void display(int n, int result, int result1) {    //output results
        System.out.println("Originl number is: " + n);
        System.out.println("\nEcrypted numebr is: " + result);
    }           //end method

    public static void display1(int n, int result, int result1) {   //output results
        System.out.println("Originl number is: " + n);
        System.out.println("\nDecrypted numebr is: " + result1);
    }           //end method

    public static void getOriginal(int n) { //return original number
        System.out.println("The original number is: \n" + n);
    }           //end method

    public static void getEncrypt(int n, int result) {  //return encrypted number
        System.out.println("The encrypted number is: \n" + result);
    }           //end method

    public static void main(String[]args, int result, int n, int result1) {
        int m = 0;
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\nPlease choose from the following menu ");
        System.out.print("\n1. Enter an original number");
        System.out.print("\n2. Encrypt the number and print it");
        System.out.print("\n3. Decrypt a number and print it");
        System.out.print("\n4. Quit\n");
        m = input1.nextInt();

        while (m < 1 || m > 4) {
            System.out.print("Error choose a number from 1-4");
            m = input1.nextInt();
        }

        if (m == 1) {
            setoriginal();
            main(args, m, m, m);
        }

        else if (m == 2) {
            if (setoriginal() == 0) {
                System.out.
                    print
                    ("Please enter an original number first");
                main(args, m, m, m);
            } else {
                encrypt(n);
                display(n, result, result1);
                main(args, n, result, result1);
            }
        } else if (m == 3) {
            if (encrypt(n) < 0) {
                System.out.
                    print("Please encrypt your number  first");
                main(args, n, result, result1);
            } else {
                decrypt(n);
                display1(n, result, result1);
                main(args, n, result, result1);
            }
        } else if (m == 4) {
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }
}
```

I get no compile errors in eclipse but I get an error stating "Selection does not contain a main type". Any ideas what could be wrong? Also if you see any other errors please could you let me know.

Comment: The method named "main" is not what java will look for.  It is looking for a specific method SIGNATURE.  It must be declared as public static void main (String[] arrayNameHere)

Comment: what do you mean by array name

Comment: I was simply trying to emphasize that the name that you assign to the variable of type String[] is irrelevant.  By convention, most people call it "args", but you can call it whatever you like.  The name of it is not part of the "method signature", which is what's really important.

Comment: i must be a pain :P but i then what would i put rather than args :S (in the case of this program)

Answer (score 5):

You should use:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

instead of:

```
public static void main(String[] args, int result, int n, int result1)
```

Comment: but don't i need to pass my parameters :S

Comment: @choloboy the parameters that you type in the command line are the elements (in the order you specified them) in the String[].  You can attempt to cast them or do whatever you like inside of the method.

Comment: sorry, i don't quite understand what you mean :S as you can probably tell I'm a beginner  :P

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[]args, int result, int n, int result1) {
```

One thing you're going to have to learn doing Java programming is the incantation:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
```

It is this exact (well, `String[] args` also works -- and the name doesn't matter) incantation that the JVM searches for when it looks for an entry point to run your program.

**Update**

If you want to get any parameters from your `main()` function they will be encoded as `String` objects in the `args[]` array. Simply index into them:

```
$ cat Echo.java ; javac Echo.java ; java Echo Hello Cruel World
import java.lang.System;

class Echo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }
}
Hello
Cruel
World
$
```

Of course, they are `String` objects. If you need to convert them into other object classes, you'll have to parse the strings correctly. (`Integer()` and similar things can come in handy for simple cases.)

Comment: how would i pass my parameters to my main if don't include them?

Answer (score 1):

In order to run your program, java needs to be able to find a method with the following signature:

```
public static void main(String[])
```

Since it can't find one in your program, it has nowhere to begin execution and hence can't compile it.

To get the affect you want, change the signature of the main method to that above, and access the arguments in terms of their indices of the String[], like so:

```
result = Integer.parseInt( args[0] );
n = Integer.parseInt( args[1] );
result1 = Integer.parseInt( args[2] );
```

If you add that to the start of your main method you should be fine. :D

Comment: i added that now ecplise is giving me compile errors on the result, n  and result on the piece of code you gave me :S

Comment: _and hence can't compile it_ -- the compiler _can_ compile it. The JVM can't _find_ it and thus can't run it.